# Django class based view with FormMixin and ListView

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am having trouble connecting my Django view with my Django template.  I am trying to use a class based view with FormMixin and ListView.

```
class Merchants(FormMixin, ListView):
    """
    A view of that shows a list of all the merchants.
    """
    template_name = "reporting/merchants.html"
    model = models.Merchant
    context_object_name = "merchants"

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(ViewClassName, self).get_queryset()
        search_query = self.request.GET.get("q", None)
        if search_query:
            queryset = queryset.filter(name__ilike=search_query)
            return queryset
```

My goal is to use my get_queryset function in my template to allow users to search for merchants.  This form is posting to itself but unfortunately it isn't returning anything. I've read Django documentation on FormMixins but still can't figure it out.  Any help would be must appreciated.

```
<form action= "">
<input name="q" placeholder="search for merchant">
<button type="submit">Search </button>
</form>
```

Thank you!

Comment: `FormMixin` isn't doing anything here and can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You have an indentation problem:

```
if search_query:
    queryset = queryset.filter(name__ilike=search_query)
    return queryset # <--- this should be outside of if statement
```

Should be:

```
if search_query:
    queryset = queryset.filter(name__ilike=search_query)
return queryset
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, unfortunately after fixing the indentation error I am still not getting any search functionality on my page.  Any other ideas?